# VBA Excel refer the string to the upper cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to refer my string to the empty cell above. I tried something like this:

```
 For Each Cell In work.Range("B3:B" & LastrouA)
 If InStr(1, Cell.Value, "Jan") > 0 Then
        Cell(-1).Value = "January"
 End If
 Next Cell
```

but it didn't work.

[image]

I want to have the month name in the empty cell (like you see above) and possibly remove the part of the string from the active cell covered by code. Is it possible?

Comment: This will not completely answer your question, but you are probably referring to using `.Offset` - `Cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value = "January"`

Comment: Use `Cell.Offset(-1, 0)`

Comment: @braX it doesn't work. It comes with nothing.

Comment: Are you sure that "Jan" really exists...? Try "Feb", like in the picture. Does it work?

Comment: Learn how to set breakpoints and step thru your code to see why. First off, what is the value of `LastrouA`? You can check all of these things by stepping thru your code and checking the variables as you go.

Comment: OK now is perfect. I made mistake because January and February were in column A, not B. Anyhow, I wasn't aware of the Offset usage here. Thank you very much for your help :)